# How to make a valid SSL Certificate / Keyfile to use with Flask SSL WSGI?

Tags: python, flask, ssl-certificate

I am writing a `Flask` Web-Application and use `eventlet` as the networking library for that application (`eventlet` is wrapped by `Flask-SocketIO` to allow asynchronous operation)

Following [this guide](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2008/12/30/howto-make-your-own-cert-with-openssl/) I have been successfully creating a SSL key- and cert-file which I pass to the WSGI Server

```
socket_io.run(app, 
              host=APP_HOST, 
              port=APP_PORT, 
              keyfile='ia.key', 
              certfile='ia.crt')
```

This works fine but unfortunately Safari / Chrome says that my SSL-Certificate is not trustworthy when I access the page for the first time. 
The Chrome-Failure is the following:

```
NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

How to I generate a valid SSL Certificate so that the browsers don't show that error when a user connects to the web application the first time!?

Comment: You need a certificate issued by a valid certificate authority or you need to add the certificate (or root certificate) to your personal machine so that it is accepted (this has no effect on others' machines)

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is something called a "Self Signed Certificate", which is not from any trusted company, so any modern browser auto-detects this as an untrusted site. If you are using a UNIX-based operating system, (Linux, or macOS, Fedora, and more), you can use what I am using. You have to generate new certification from a trusted site.

This is what I use to get a TRUSTED certificate that most browsers can use: `https://certbot.eff.org/instructions`.